# wifi sometimes connect sometimes does not connect

Tags: wireless, connection

people please help sometimes my wifi works on the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but sometimes when I restart the system again after a few hours it does not show any wifi and says no wifi adapter is found now the issue is it is there but it does not work, so I have to restart the system multiple times and wait that it might connect to the wifi.

I am fed up please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQKUZ.png)

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.